# Використання слова "челендж"?

Tags: значення-слів, іншомовні-слова

Як зрозуміти назву заходу:*"Насіннєвий **челендж** у Києві! Зберігаємо біорізноманітність разом!"*.

В подробицях до події зазначено:

> Насіннєвий **челендж** це обмін насінням від:
>
> - дослідних станцій та науково-дослідних інститутів,
> - органічних сертифікованих фермерів (по органічним стандартам: не ГМО, не оброблене, ідентифікований сорт, якісні властивості),
> - колекцій монастирів,
> - сорти народної селекції та фамільні сорти.

***"Challenge"*** з англійського на українську перекладається, як 
***"виклик"***.

Чи правильно вживати саме слово ***"челендж"***? Чи правильно сформована назва заходу?